# Ruby, Hash-append an element to existing value

Tags: ruby

I am trying to add an element to a hash value.
Example:

```
tally={}
tally["aa"]=[1]
tally["aa"].append(2)  => so it should be tally["aa"]=[1,2]
```

my code:

```
def list_duplicates(seq)
    tally = {}
    seq.each_with_index do |item,i|         
      if tally[item].nil?
        tally[item]=[i]         
      else          
        tally[item].add(i)
      end
    end
    a=tally.keys()
    b=tally.values()
    if b.length>1
      return [a,b]
    end
end


sourse=["AAA","GGG","AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB","agaha"]
list_duplicates(sourse).each do |l|
    puts(l)

end
```

but it shows me an error:

```
undefined method `append' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
```

How can I append an item to a value of existing item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use `push` or `<<` instead of `append`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `push()` or `<<`. There is no `append()`in Ruby when it comes to the `Array` class

`tally["aa"].push(a)` or `tally["aa"] << a`

[Documentation for Array here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "append" method for Array shown in the Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html). And your code sample shows `add`, not `append`, which also is not a method for Array. Use `tally[item] << i`.